# Что означает эта ошибка "lvalue required as unary '&' operand"?

Tags: c++, c

Собственно вот и вопрос!
Вот в каком случай она у меня выходит.

```
del(&(search(head)));
```

функция `search(head)` возвращает указатель на объект. А функция `del` реализовано так

`del(cOBJECT **a);`

Comment: А в каком коде это произошло?

Comment: Вот в каком случай она у меня выходит. del(&(search(head))); функция search(head) возвращает указатель на объект. А функция del реализовано так del(coBJECT **a);

Comment: Это C/C++/C#? тогда я бессилен XD sorry

Comment: Язык C/C++

Comment: А что означает `del (&(search(head)));`? Какой результат даёт search(head)? Ну да это вторично. Рассмотрим на уровень пониже. search возвращает результат в регистре. Что будет означать `&(search(head))`? (По идее -- откровенный бред)

Comment: А почему функция `del` требует именно `cOBJECT **`. Почему именно двойной указатель?

Answer (score 5):

- В вашем случае решить проблему можно следующим образом:

  ```
  cOBJECT* searchResult = search(head);
  del(&searchResult);
  ```
- Разумеется, рекомендую почитать про **[lvalue и rvalue в С++.](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html)**

  ```
  int foo();
  int j = 0;
  j = foobar(); // foo() это rvalue, так делать можно
  int* p2 = &foo(); // Ошибка - нельзя взять адрес от rvalue
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы взять адрес чего-то с помощью оператора `&`, надо, чтобы это что-то находилось в оперативной памяти.

В оперативной памяти могут находиться только *lvalue*-значения, то есть именованные сущности. Пока сущности не присвоено имя, она является *rvalue* и считается неименованой, неадресуемой, находящейся неизвестно где и готовой быть уничтоженной в любой момент (либо переданной дальше по цепочке, если речь идёт о C++11 и выше).

Поэтому для возможности взятия адреса сущности её необходимо закрепить за какой-нибудь переменной, хотя бы локальной.